# How to access Entiydatamodel in T4 template

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, t4

I want to access my entity data model in T4 templates.
    I want to generate some code from database in t4 template.

```
    ex: using(var context=new Mymodel())
    {
    //db operations
    }

Please help me
thank you....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the parameter to your template.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586944(v=vs.120).aspx